# Old version of MVC app appearing after deploying to azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have our ASP.NET MVC app hosted in an App Service in Azure. We have production and then a dev slot for staging.

Deploying to staging is reflected correctly when logging into the site.

When we publish to production, it will display on old version of the site and use an older version of the back-end (not client side caching issue).

The strange thing is, this seems to be only happening for some people (possibly in different regions etc). So basically, User 1 could see the correct updated site, while User 2 is seeing an older version.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: There's an easy way to check what's deployed in the PROD slot. Open [Kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/04/01/the-kudu-debug-console-azure-websites-best-kept-secret/) and navigate to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`.

Comment: Could this be related to browser cache?

Comment: No, its the server side and client side logic. The correct files are on in Kudu. If i look at the site via my VM its fine, if i look at it from my other machine its an older version.

Comment: There is a "Testing in production" feature, for the App Service which might cause the same what you just described. Can you please check if this feature is turned off for you? Here is some description about it: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABTestingAndTestingInProductionWithAzureWebApps.aspx